# For loop in shell script with integer as input

Tags: shell, loops

I am trying to take integer as a input and trying to print numbers from 1 to the input number.
How can I do that?

Comment: *How could you write it?*

Comment: Regarding the integer input: you can get an input by using $1 (this will be the first argument). Regarding the loop: you should look here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

Comment: How can I do it from 1 to 2*input?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
read -p "Loop until: " n
for i in $(seq 1 $n); do
    echo $i;
done
```

`$n` will contain the user input.
The `seq` program simply builds a sequence of numbers from 1 to `$n`, and the for loop prints every item in this sequence.

Comment: I don't want it as as a command line argument but as a prompt input as we take from "read" command. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Note that `seq` is not standard, and on some platforms does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using seq command you can use the arithmetic initialisation in a shell.
You can use the following code to do it.

```
$ cat test
#!/bin/bash


read -p "Loop until: " n
a=1
while true; do
    if [ $a -le $n ]; then
        echo $a
    else
        break
    fi
a=$(($a+1))
done

$ sh test
Loop until: 4
1
2
3
4
```